# how to show 2 value and one values count from 3 table using mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables

**Table1 (theoryquestion)**

```
id | question | mark | technology
```

**Table2 (mark)**

```
 mark | id
```

**Table3 (technologies)**

```
technology | id
```

I want to select count of question from corresponding mark and tech,

I have tried this

```
SELECT m.mark_name
     , t.techname
     , COUNT(q.question) 
  FROM question_mark m
  JOIN theoryquestion q
    on q.mark = m.mark_name 
   and q.technology = t.techname 
  JOIN technologies
```

Comment: Please improve your question (example data, expected outcome, observed outcome, etc.) https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a proper on clause for join the table technologies
and use group by for trigger the aggregation function (count)

```
SELECT 
    question_mark.mark_name
    ,technologies.techname
    ,COUNT(theoryquestion.question) 
FROM question_mark 
INNER JOIN theoryquestion on theoryquestion.mark=question_mark.mark_name 
INNER JOIN technologies theoryquestion.technology=technologies.techname 
GROUP BY  question_mark.mark_name ,technologies.techname
```

Answer (score -2):

this worked for me..........
thank zzz

`SELECT question_mark.mark_name,technologies.techname,COUNT(theoryquestion.question) FROM theoryquestion INNER JOIN question_mark on theoryquestion.mark=question_mark.mark_name INNER JOIN technologies on theoryquestion.technology=technologies.techname GROUP BY question_mark.mark_name ,technologies.techname`

Comment: Do not copy the answer. Accept the anwer given by @scaisEdge